# TSQL select the from two rows that has higher priority and is not null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I try to consolidate two rows of the same table whereas each row has a priority. 
The value of interest is the value having priority 1 if it is not NULL; otherwise the value with priority 0.

An example data source could be:

```
| Id | GroupId | Priority | Col1  | Col2  | Col3  | ... | Coln  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1       | 0        | NULL  | 4711  | 3.41  | ... | f00   |
| 2  | 1       | 1        | NULL  | NULL  | 2.83  | ... | bar   |    
| 3  | 2       | 0        | NULL  | 4711  | 3.41  | ... | f00   |
| 4  | 2       | 1        | 23    | NULL  | 2.83  | ... | NULL  |
```

and I want to have:

```
| GroupId | Col1  | Col2  | Col3  | ... | Coln  |
-------------------------------------------------
| 1       | NULL  | 4711  | 2.83  | ... | bar   |    
| 2       | 23    | 4711  | 2.83  | ... | f00   |
```

Is there a generic way in TSQL without the need to check each column explicitly?

```
SELECT 
  t1.GroupId,
  ISNULL(t2.Col1, t1.Col1) as Col1,
  ISNULL(t2.Col2, t1.Col2) as Col2,
  ISNULL(t2.Col3, t1.Col3) as Col3,
  ...
  ISNULL(t2.Coln, t1.Coln) as Coln
FROM mytable t1
JOIN mytable t2 ON t1.GroupId = t2.GroupId
WHERE       
    t1.Priority = 0 AND
    t2.Priority = 1
```

Regards

Comment: What you have seems the most direct solution.  What is your concern that makes you feels this is not appropriate?

Comment: Nope, you are doing it right.

Comment: for a "generic" solution that will work with any number of rows, look at `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GroupId ORDER BY ISNULL(Priority,-1) ) AS RowID`. You'll need to put this in a derived table or CTE and then add `WHERE RowID=1` to filter that derived table/CTE.

Comment: Well I just wanted to know if there is a solution which prevents me from specifying each column explicitly. @KM: How can I select the correct value (for a particular column) with a partition by?

Comment: if you have lots of columns to do, you might want to consider making them rows. if not, then use a `row_number()` for each column where the column is not null and then join them all together.

Answer (score 1):

I'll elaborate the ROW_NUMBER() solution that @KM suggested since IMO it's the best solution for this. (In CTE form for easier readability)

```
WITH cte AS (   
   SELECT
      t1.GroupId,
      t1.Col1,
      t1.Col2,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t1.GroupId ORDER BY ISNULL(GroupId ,-1) ) AS [row_id]
   FROM
      mytable t1
)
SELECT 
   *
FROM
   cte 
WHERE 
   row_id = 1
```

That will give you the row with the highest priority (according to your rules) for each GroupId in mytable.

ROW_NUMBER and RANK are two of my favorite TSQL tricks. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

edit: Another favorite of mine is PIVOT/UNPIVOT which you can use to transpose rows/columns which is another way of going about this type of problem. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do what you are asking for without using isnull for every column

```
select
   *
from
   mytable t1
where
   priority=(select max(priority) from mytable where groupid=t1.groupid group by groupid)
```

Comment: If you are looking for a column by column higher priority then this will not help you.  Sorry for any confusion

Comment: This is only selecting the row having max priority, isn't it? This is not what I want.